# morphological operations in matlab and simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, operation

I got some issues concerning the `simulink morphological block erode`. I'm using a `3x3 neighborhood` the for the operation (`strel('square',3)` is set at the function block parameters ). Everything is just working fine as long as the found object points aren't located at the image borders. If they're, the outcome of the block `erode` still contains the border points of the image, but actually due to the `erode` operation they should have been gone. Am I not fully understanding the block or what's my basic mistake here? If I'm using the `matlab function` `bwmorph()` for eroding the image, it gives me the desired outcome, which I'm actually expecting.

If it can't be fixed, I'll have to implement the operation as a `matlab function block` in `simulink`. If I do so, can anyone tell me about the runtime increse or decrease, that I'm getting? The final algorithm will be compiled to a rapid prototyping platform via a simulink interface.

Best regards!

Comment: How are you using bwmorph to erode the image? Can you post the command?

Comment: I'm using it like this: imgOut = bwmorph(imgIn,'erode');

Comment: I do not see this behavior. How big is the border? If you plan to use bwmorph you need to make sure bwmorph is supported by MATLAB Function block for code generation.

Comment: consider the example of a rectangle or square, that is placed at a corner of the image. when you erode the image with simulink, the points connected to the borderpixel will stay. but because I want to extract the edges of a binary image, and therefore I also consider borderpixel as edges.